# How to get generic type from object type

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

My Classes are;

```
class BaseClass
{

}

class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{

}

class GenericClass<T>
{

}

class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
{
    GenericClass<DerivedClass1> subItem;
}
```

I want to access all fields of DerivedClass2 class.
I use System.Reflection and FieldInfo.GetValue() method;

Bu I cant get subItem field.
FieldInfo.GetValue() method return type is "object".
And I cant cast to `GenericClass<DerivedClass1>`
or 
I cant get DerivedClass1 type.
I try this with BaseClass

```
BaseClass instance = FieldInfo.Getvalue(this) as GenericClass<BaseClass>;
```

but instance is null.
How to get instance with type or how to get only type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but his works for me:

```
var foo = new DerivedClass2();
var result = typeof(DerivedClass2).GetField("subItem", 
                                            BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                            BindingFlags.Instance)
                                  .GetValue(foo);
var genericClassField = result as GenericClass<DerivedClass1>;
```

`genericClassField`  is of type `GenericClass<DerivedClass1>` - of course you have to assign it a value before doing this, otherwise result will be `null`, for this I added a constructor to your `DerivedClass2` that does just that:

```
class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
{
    GenericClass<DerivedClass1> subItem;

    public DerivedClass2()
    {
        subItem = new GenericClass<DerivedClass1>();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

To find out the type of `result`  at runtime you could do the following:

```
var foo = new DerivedClass2();
var result = typeof(DerivedClass2).GetField("subItem", 
                                            BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                            BindingFlags.Instance)
                                  .GetValue(foo);
Type myType = result.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

In the example this would return the type `DerivedClass1`. Also I think this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx) might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But my problem is I dont know DerivedClass1 type. It is generic. All classes which derived class from DBObject will be avaible.

Comment: Thanks BrokenGlass,
I have resolved it with different way. I write a base class for GenericClass and All fields of GenericClass are in this base class.
So I can use all of them.